# Schedule a flow to run every week and if a expired date in the library is passed todays date then...

Tags: document-library, microsoft-flow, flow

I wanting to schedule a microsoft flow to run every week and if the expired date in a document library is greater than the current date, then create a planner entry to work as a reminder for the employee to update the document.  Is this possible and if so, how?

I can schedule a flow every week but I can't see how to then relate that flow a field in a document library.  Any pointers, appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On of the actions is "get Files (properties only). This action allows you to get a list of files from a library, and you can even specify a filter in the advanced properties. So point it to your library, and set the filter so it only returns items that are expired. Then, after that action, create the planner entry as needed. This last step will take place inside of a loop, so it will happen for each document that is returned from the prior step.